# Difference between os.path.exists and os.path.isfile?

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm curious when these two functions will return different values. Also if  you could clarify the difference between a path/directory/file that would be appreciated.

Comment: `os.path.isfile` will return false if the argument is not a file: that is, it is a directory, or it does not exist.

Comment: os.path.exists returns if it is a valid path(check for directory or file, both) and os.path.isfile(checks for only file, not directory) returns if it is a file. so when os.path.isfile is True, os.path.exists also True and when os.path.exists is False, os.path.isfile is also False. hope this makes you understood. cheers ! :)

Comment: To better understand, think of `isfile` as `exists_as_file` ;)

Answer (score 46):

As you have already found out, the difference between `exists` and `isfile` is the fact that the former returns `True` in case the given path is a directory **or** a file, while the latter only returns `True` if the path points to a file.

**Directories** and **files** are quite similar from the technical point of view. A file can contain any kind of data. A directory is just a special entry in the file system (at least on Unix operating systems it is just a special file) that represents the fact that it may contain files and other directories. It is a helpful means for building up a data structure. Using directories, you can organize your data in a hierarchical structure.

Especially in the Windows world, directories are often called "folders". I am sure that you yourself are using "folders" for organizing your files.

A **path** is an unambiguous pointer to a resource in the file system. It can either point to a file or to a directory.

Comment: So if isfile(x) returns true, does exists(x) return true every time?

Comment: Yes, `isfile(path) == True` implicates `exists(path) == True`.

Answer (score 4):

A directory tests true for exists, but false for isfile. There are a few different types of filesystem objects for which that is also true.

isfile means that it is a regular file. It is more specific than exists.

Answer (score 0):

os.path.exists returns if it is a valid path(check for directory or file, both) whereas os.path.isfile(checks for only file, not directory)