# Python argparse input file error

Tags: python, argparse

I've seen similar problems, but not a solution that works for this case. I have an argparser function:

```
def IO_fileParse():
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser();
     parser.add_argument("-i", dest="input_file", help="no file with this name") 
     args = parser.parse_args();

     input_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),args.input_file)
     if not os.path.exists(input_file):
         print(" ------------------------------------------------");
         print("Error: -input_file Cannot find input file with that name.");
         print(" ------------------------------------------------");
         parser.print_help();
         sys.exit();
```

I want to say "if you can't find a file with the -i name in the directory, print the help and exit the script."

What actually happens is that this seems to make an empty file with the name of the input file?

How do I change the above code to say "if -i file does not exist, tell user this file does not exist" (and don't make an empty file with the file name that doesn't exist).

I've also tried os.path.isfile and os.path.exists, and neither give me the error I want either?...and I've also tried if not args.input_file too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between os.path.exists and os.path.isfile in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752078/difference-between-os-path-exists-and-os-path-isfile-in-python)

Comment: `if not args.input_file` since it is optional?

Comment: I've also tried os.path.isfile and os.path.exists, and neither give me the error I want either?...and I've also tried if not args.input_file too.

Comment: Do you have any calls to `open()` for the file? I dont see anything in code that would make a file.. and make sure you delete the file before testing (in case that wasnt obvious :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take out semicolons. Why are they there?
2. You are not properly accessing the variable.
3. You are storing it in a variable called -i. Try calling it -input_file, remove the, dest, and access it through args.input_file
4. os.getcwd(), will give you the working directory, not the current path. To get the current path `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__"))`
5. I do not know if you are calling it right, but with the my proposed structure the usage would be `python test.py -input_file filename`

edit: you can supply shorthand option and full form via `parser.add_argument("-i", "--input_name")`

This code works for me

```
def IO_fileParse():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-input_file", help="no file with this name")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    input_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),args.input_file)
    print(input_file)
    if not os.path.exists(input_file):
        print(" ------------------------------------------------")
        print("Error: -input_file Cannot find input file with that name.")
        print(" ------------------------------------------------")
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()

IO_fileParse()
```

Comment: Normally, '-i' is the short flag form, '--input_file' (or '--input-file') the long. (one dash with short, two with long).  `dest` is deduced from the first long, but may also be given explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestions, I copied exactly into my code and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Other than minor tweaks I don't see a problem with your script. Here's my test:

```
In [52]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [53]: p.add_argument('-i','--input-file')
...
```

Without the flagged option, the default is `None`, and the path join does not work.  It should be given a valid default or use a `if args.input_file is not None:` test.

```
In [54]: args=p.parse_args(''.split())    
In [55]: args
Out[55]: Namespace(input_file=None)

In [56]: name=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),args.input_file)
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

with an existing file name:

```
In [57]: args=p.parse_args('-i test'.split())
In [58]: args
Out[58]: Namespace(input_file='test')
In [59]: name=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),args.input_file)
In [60]: name
Out[60]: '/home/paul/test'   # valid file name
In [61]: os.path.exists(name)
Out[61]: True    # it exists on my system
```

with a name choosen at random

```
In [62]: args=p.parse_args('-i random'.split())
In [63]: name=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),args.input_file)
In [65]: os.path.exists(name)
Out[65]: False    # it doesn't exist
```

And repeating the `exists` test shows that nothing creates the file.